# I'm using Servlets and can't seem to figure out why my download file servlet will work locally, but not otherwise

Tags: java, file, jsp, servlets, download

When I dl from localhost, it works fine. When I put the code online, it doesn't work. I get a nullpointer exception. The file is definitely in the "Files" folder in the Web Content folder.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType(".pdf");
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition","attachment; filename=Web_Resume.pdf");
    File myresume = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/Files/Web_Resume.pdf"));
    OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(myresume);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int length;
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0){
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    in.close();
    out.flush();
    }
```

Comment: Where are you deploying your code?  For example, Google App Engine only allows reading files from the WEB-INF folder.  Your provider may have similar limitations.

Comment: Unrelated, but `response.setContentType(".pdf");` should be `response.setContentType("application/pdf");`.

Comment: Have you reviewed the logs on your deploy server?

Comment: I changed the file location to the WEB-INF and it still didn't work. I'm deploying using eclipse and Tomcat for now. I'm sort of a beginner so I don't know how to access the logs :( sorry

Comment: Also i changed it to application/pdf :)

Comment: You're deploying using Eclipse and Tomcat from localhost to... where? What kind of server?

Answer (score 0):

If it is being deployed as a archive online (.war file, versus exploded on your local file system) then according to the JavaDoc for ServletContext, getRealPath(...) may return null, which would then cause a NullPointerException in the File constructore - see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath(java.lang.String)